# g++ std::is_function implementation: what does _ArgTypes followed by 6 periods mean?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, variadic-templates

I was looking at my headers (g++-4.5.2) for the implementations of some templates in , and I found the following:

```
/// is_function
template<typename>
  struct is_function
  : public false_type { };
template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
  struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
  : public true_type { };
template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
  struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>
  : public true_type { };
```

The first two declarations seem reasonable, but I can't figure out how the third works. What is `......`? I looked for it in the standard, and couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you want C++11 you should use at least GCC 4.7, not 4.5 (which was released much before the C++2011 standard)

Comment: It's equivalent to `_ArgTypes..., ...`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'm not actually writing C++11 code yet. I was just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
_Res(_ArgTypes..., ...)
```

The comma before an ellipses parameter is optional.

Comment: How does that differ from `_Res(_ArgTypes...)`?

Comment: @BrianBi: Imagine you passed `printf` to this. `_ArgTypes` would hold `const char*`, and the final `...` is needed to match, since no type represent it.

Comment: *"The comma before an ellipses parameter is optional"* - What the? Amazing! +1

Comment: Curiously, it is only optional in C++ (not C).

Answer (score 0):

This template deal with variable-length parameter in a function. For example:

```
void foo(bool, char, int...)
```